# Getting stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: c++

I had my program running smoothly, and then after commenting it and adding some final touches, it stopped working on me. The function that I am having problems with is using  several objects/functions defined elsewhere, so I am just wondering if someone can affirm that my logic is correct and that the infinite loop is not a product of a syntax error. Thanks for your time, here is the problem I'm having:

If the cashier started a new order and wants to close his order, `T` is typed in. However, when trying to exit an order and loop back to the start of `while(moreCustomers)`, nothing is happening. I am trying to exit the `while(moreItems)` loop by setting `moreItems = false;`, but after doing that, it gets stuck in the `while(moreItems)` loop and does not go back to `while(moreCustomers)`. Does the syntax make sense, and should I be able to break the loop by setting `moreItems = false;`?

```
bool moreCustomers = true;      
while (moreCustomers)
{ 
    // get input to start new order or close register
    drawInstruct("Enter N to start a new order or E to\n close the register.");
    char* setFmt = "@"; // the input must be a letter
    char input[7];      // char array that stores input from cashier
    s.GetStr(xLeftCoord + 1, yTopCoord + 1, input, 1, setFmt, true);   

    for(int x = 1; x < 10; x++) // clear the input field
    {  
        s.ClearScreenPos(x, 1);
    }        

    if (input[0] == 'N') // if a new order is requested
    {   
        bool moreItems = true;  

        while (moreItems)
        {                  
            getInput(input);        

            if(input[1]) // if input is not a single char
            {
                if (input[0] == 'M') // get the desired number of multiples for the current item and update the tape and display area accordingly
                {                       
                    custTape.handleMultiples(atoi(input)); // adds multiples to tape
                    curVal = isUPC->price * (atoi(input)); // updates the current item price                            
                    drawDisplayArea(curVal);               // updates the display area
                }
                else // invalid number of multiples, prompt for new multiple
                {
                    drawInstruct("Invalid command. Please try again.");
                    s.Delay();
                }                    
            }
            else if (input[0] == 'T') // close the order
            { 

                 drawInstruct("Order cancelled.");
                 s.Delay();                                                         
                 moreItems = false; // customer order is complete, exit loop                    
            }
            else // invalid command, get new input from the cashier
            {
                drawInstruct("Invalid command. Please try again.");
                s.Delay();
            }
        }
    }
    else if (input[0] == 'E') // close the register
    {               
        moreCustomers = false; // no more customers, exit the program
    }
    else // invalid command, get new input from the cashier
    {
        drawInstruct("Invalid Command. Please try again.");
        s.Delay();
    }
}
```

I can't exit `else if(input[0] == 'T')`, and any commands I enter in after `moreItems = false;` work correctly.

Comment: This kind of code is a good example why factoring out is a great tool. I am reluctant to look for problems in this code.

Comment: What do you mean by factoring out? I can understand if is hard to help when there are no explanations of the code being used, but there is a decent amount of code needed to understand it. I am only trying to figure out if the moreItems boolean I'm using should technically exit the loop, didn't think extra code would necessarily help with that

Comment: Start by stepping through the program, and watch what happens each time you go through the loop, but especially watch to see what *does not* change (for things that would lead to leaving the loop).

Comment: It's too much code to easily spot the problem (consider writing a separate function for each operation) but `0 < atoi(input) < 100` does *not* do an interval test - it tests if `0 < atoi(input)` is less than 100. Since `0 < atoi(input)` is a boolean, it's converted to 0 or 1 when compared to 100, so the condition is always true.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, when I was testing my program I did notice that I could enter in any input and it would work.

Comment: @cjw Do you know about debuggers? Why don't you just debug your code?

Comment: I wasn't getting anything from the debugger since there are no errors, not sure how I can utilize it. But any code after moreItems = false works, any code at the start of the while(moreCustomers) loop does not, and moreItems is being correctly set to false.

Comment: You can put a breakpoint to stop the execution inside your loop (or where you want) and watch the values that control your loop. You don't need an error to use a debugger.

Comment: @cjw The debugger is not about "errors", but about inspecting results and state. Step through, line by line. Look at the values of variables. Are they changing like you expect? Is `input` changing like expected (since that seems like a key to the problem)?

Comment: I don't know how to use a debugger properly then, but I am also thinking that input could be the problem. I'm going to try to figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd set a breakpoint on the first moreItems = false; line to see if it is ever being hit. My guess is that it is not. You've tagged the question with Visual Studio, so if that is what you're using see this link for how to set a breakpoint:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k80ex6de%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Basically a breakpoint causes your program to stop at that line. Also try setting a breakpoint on this line:

```
if (input[0] == 'N')
```

Run the program, press a key, and wait for the breakpoint to be hit. Then use the "Step Over" option on the Debug menu. This runs your program line by line, each time you press "Step Over" (F10 does this too, much quicker). Keep stepping to see what path of execution occurs through your code. You may also be able to hover over variables to see their values.

Theres loads on the net about debugging with visual studio, but if you master the above you'll be well away

Comment: Following the suggestions given before, I set a breakpoint and was able to finally see the values in my variables. 'moreItems = false' is being hit, all my values are correct after it is called, but when I break out of the 'if(input[0] == 'N')' statement, my input[] field is wrong. So I am assuming that my syntax is right and that the problem lies elsewhere. I'll try the "Step Over" option that seems very useful.

Comment: What do you mean by "my input[] field is wrong"? Note that if you hover over the name of an array you'll just see the address of the first element and maybe an attempt at showing the whole string. Hover over the sqaure brackets to get the value of that specific element

Comment: I saw what char was in each element of input[] and it was not what I expected